# Is it possible to break long lines in sshd_config?

Tags: ssh, configuration

Specifically `AllowUsers` parameter:

e.g. convert this

```
AllowUsers user1 user2 user3 user4
```

to this

```
AllowUsers
    user1
    user2
    user3
    user4
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, but it's not useful in this case. You can have multiple `AcceptEnv`, `AllowGroups`, `AllowUsers`, `DenyGroups`, `DenyUsers`, `HostKey`, `PermitOpen`, `Port` and `Subsystem` lines, and each line adds one or more (or sometimes zero) elements to the list.

Nonetheless, if you can't easily fit your `AllowUsers` directive on one line, I suggest creating a `ssh_allowed` group and using `AllowGroups ssh_allowed` in `sshd_config`.

Comment: Oh, good point about just having multiple `AllowUsers` directives

Comment: One word of caution, looks like `AllowGroups` and `AllowUsers` do not tolerate each other (multiple entries of the same type are OK).  So, in you configuration stick to either policy, but not both.

Comment: You can use both `AllowGroups` and `AllowUsers` but if you do the OpenSSH daemon will only let the allowed users log in if they are also in an allowed group. In other words, it's "and" (intersection), not "or" (union).

Comment: It would be useful in the case of making `KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256` more readable

Comment: Notice that (at least) with OpenSSH7.4 this only seems to work if all `AllowUsers` lines are "en bloc", without other settings in between. I have tested it with a config file where after the first `AllowUsers` directive there was `Match User` block, and then two more `AllowUsers` lines. Only the users of the first `AllowUsers` line were able to login. After moving the other lines directly below the first `AllowUsers` lines, the other users were again able to log on.

Comment: @AdminBee `AllowUsers` lines after a `Match` directive only apply when the `Match` directive matches. There's no way to “close” a `Match` block.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I see. I hadn't grasped that aspect of the SSH config syntax (although it does make sense, come to think of it). Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 13):

In short, it looks like no

OpenSSH's `servconf.c` dumps the file into a buffer without checking for such things (all it appears to do is look for `#` to mark a comment):

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)) {
    if ((cp = strchr(line, '#')) != NULL)
        memcpy(cp, "\n", 2);
    cp = line + strspn(line, " \t\r");

    buffer_append(conf, cp, strlen(cp));
}
```

The function that parses the config then splits the buffer on newlines and processes each line:

```
while ((cp = strsep(&cbuf, "\n")) != NULL) {
    if (process_server_config_line(options, cp, filename,
        linenum++, &active, user, host, address) != 0)
    bad_options++;
}
```